# Dynamic Bootstrap Tab not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Here is the situation, I have the ability to create a new tab on fly with the following code:

Here is the jquery:

```
   $(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
.on("click", "span", function () {
    var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
    $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
});

$('.add-address').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
    $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#address_'+id+'" data-toggle="tab">Additional Address</a><span>x</span></li>');
    $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="address_'+id+'">Test Address '+id+'</div>');
 });
```

Here is the HTML

```
  <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
                  <li <?php  echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="#address_01" data-toggle="tab" class="ticket-tab-button"><?php _e('Primary Address'); ?></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#address_02" data-toggle="tab" class="ticket-tab-button"><?php _e('Additional Address'); ?></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="add-address">+ Add Address</a>
             </ul>

             <div class="tab-content" id="test">
                 <div  class="tab-pane active" id="address_01">Address #1</div>
                 <div  class="tab-pane" id="address_02">Address #2</div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

What the problem, is that the new tab is being created, however, the information, is not being in the correct spot. It should go on the bottom, however, it is being placed elsewhere.

Why is the content for the dynamic tabs is not going to the right spot?

I'm using Bootstrap 3 just as an FYI.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just found out.

I changed the following code from:

```
  $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="address_'+id+'">Test Address '+id+'</div>');
```

To:

```
 $('#test').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="address_'+id+'">Test Address '+id+'</div>');
```

That did the trick.